# Highlighting circles by mouseover that have duplicate names

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a search box that highlights all circles when they have the same name and fades out the circles that don't match. All working as expected.

```
<input class="highlight" name="searchbox" id="searchbox" type="text" list="initname-datalist" placeholder="Search Project/Initiative.." onInput="initiativeSearch(this.value)">
<datalist id="initname-datalist"></datalist>

function initiativeSearch(initSelection) {
  circles.transition()
    .delay(0)
    .duration(500)
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
      return d.data.initiative_name !== initSelection ? 0.5 : 1;
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.data.initiative_name === initSelection ? "black" : "grey";
    });
}
```

`initiative_name` is a column name in my CSV. I want to do a similar thing but using `mouseover`, so when a user `mouseover` a circle all other circles with the same name will be highlighted.

I have a current `mouseover` in place that adds a yellow stroke to the circle being moused over and also a tool tip. I don't necessarily need to retain the yellow stroke.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this) // highlight the circle that the tooltip relates to
        .transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(100)
        .style("stroke", "yellow")
        .style("stroke-width", 5);
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .95);
      tooltip.html("<strong>" + d.data.initiative_name + "</strong>)
        .style("left", d3.select(this).attr("cx") + "px")
        .style("top", d3.select(this).attr("cy") + "px");
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(500)
        .style("stroke", "grey")
        .style("stroke-width", 1);
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });
```

Any ideas how I can highlight all circles with the same `initiative_name` using `mouseover`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to write a solution without actually testing it with the data, but this is a possible one:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    circles.style("opacity", function(e) {
      return d.data.initiative_name !== e.data.initiative_name ? 0.5 : 1;
    });
    //etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, that works perfect. Do you know if it's possible to have a tooltip appear for all items that have the same initiative_name? I can get tooltip working on individual circles but unsure if I'm limited to one tooltip at a time.

Comment: I suggest you post this as a new question, with all the relevant details and, this time, with a running code. That way it will be easier for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Call `initiativeSearch()` on mouseover like this

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
   initiativeSearch(d.data.initiative_name);  
}
```